# recursively read in csv files and perform calculation on two files

Tags: r

I have a list of files I would like to import, perform a calculation and save the result.

I have a few folders labeled as follows:

`2005`, `2006`, `2007`... `2018`.

The files are saved as:

`file_2005.csv`, `file_2006.csv`, `file_2007.csv`... `file_2018.csv`.

(one file per folder)

I am trying to write a function which will do the following:

- read in `file_2005.csv` and `file_2006.csv` from folder `2005` and `2006` respectively.
- perform some cleaning, processing and some calculations on these 2 datasets.
- save the results.

-- read in `file_2006.csv` and now `file_2007.csv` from folder `2006` and `2007`.
-- perform the same calculations as before.
-- save the results.

--- read in `file_2007.csv` and `file_2008.csv` from folder `2007` and `2008`.

--- perform same calculations

--- save the results.

etc...

So I would like to know how I can recursively créate such a function which essentially reads in all the data and processes the results.

When I read in all of the years together I obtain memory issues.

Comment: `frames <- sapply(list.files(path, pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE. recursive=TRUE), read.csv, simplify = FALSE)`, process each frame, then something like `Map(function(x,fn) write.csv(x, fn, row.names=FALSE), frames, names(frames))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List the files

```
LF <- list.files(path="Years",pattern=".csv",full.names=T,recursive=T)
```

Create a data.frame with two columns - 1 with all years less the last, and the other with all columns less the first

```
data <- data.frame(V1=LF[-c(length(LF))])
data$V2 <- LF[-c(1)]
```

Then split into list of data frames by row

```
li <- split(data, seq(nrow(data)))
```

Then read in both files in each row (i.e. one year in column 1 and the next in col 2. Do this using lapply, where you can also apply the function `f(x)` and write the csv outputs. I have used `sprintf` to customise the file names

```
RF <- lapply(li, function(x) {
  dat1 <- read.csv(as.character(x$V1))
  dat2 <- read.csv(as.character(x$V2))
  ndat1 <- f(dat1)
  ndat2 <- f(dat2)
  write.csv (ndat1, sprintf("new_%s",x$V1))
  write.csv (ndat2, sprintf("new_%s",x$V2))
})
```